# text-overflow: ellipsis fighting with direction: rtl

Tags: html, css, email

I like displaying emails properly, meaning not [at]. 
To fight the bots I reverse the text in the html and then re-reverse it with css using `direction: rtl`. That worked fine for many many years, until an email dared to break lines.

You can see what happens on the screenshots; kinda hard to explain–

*Thats the mess that happens*
[image: Thats the mess that happens]

*This is how it looks when there is enough space*
[image: And this is how it should look]

The http-host is always the same, so I figured using `text-overflow: ellipsis` together with `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow: hidden` on the `<a>`. That went south aswell;

(side note: it wasn't possible for me to fully highlight the visible text?)
(The end of the highlight is NOT the end of the box!)
[image]

Okay; the text-overflow clipping comes first, then the reversing; I get it.
So lets put `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` on the parent, which is a `<p>` and the `white-space: nowrap` on the `a` (scared that a telephone number will get chopped off)

I played around with a combination which styles go to the `p` and which to the `a` .. and I had one solution (which I unfortunately can't reproduce oO) where the dots were at the right side (which is what I want) but the text still gets chopped of an the visual left of the outcome, meaning the name name of the email, which I do not want to clip!

[image]

Long question short..
How can I get the following result?
`S.Rossa@park-reside...`

When my email markup looks like this:

```
<a href="/email.php?to=rossa" class="direction">
<?php echo strrev("S.Rossa@park-residenz-alfeld.de"); ?>
</a>
```

Out of many reasons I cannot go back from the `direction: rtl` thing on the emails.

Please keep that in mind when suggesting a way to

1. keep the email from breaking lines, no matter what
2. and a convenient way to clip it with ...
3. with css only

Thanks!

Comment: try giving max-width to `a` - anchor, this would bring `ellipsis`.

Comment: Thanks :) Found that out aswell. Unforutnately that doesn't solve the main issue. I don't the beginning of the email clipped.

Answer (score 2):

The browser is given a string. When you tell it to shrink it and replace what doesn't fit with an `ellipsis`, it will always cut from the end of the string. It doesn't know your string is reversed and it trusts you when you tell it: **this string should be read from right to left** (`direction:rtl`). The end is on the left side.

Therefore, with CSS alone, the closest (and most decent) thing you can get is cutting from left side and placing the `ellipsis` where the cut was made:

```css
a.direction {
  direction: rtl;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  /* proof of concept: */
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="/email.php?to=rossa" class="direction">&#x202e;ed.dlefla-znediser-krap@assoR.S</a>
```

You have two options now. Either

1. give up on `text-overflow: ellipsis` and fake it using JavaScript (works, but it's ugly) or...
2. you could reverse the string before you render it and give up on `direction: rtl` (which is actually a trick, it's not correct and is the source of the problem). Of course, you need to make sure you only do this for browsers, not for bots. The easiest way would be to check `navigator.userAgent`:

```js
if (!/bot|crawler|spider|crawling/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  var directions = document.querySelectorAll('.direction');
  for (var i = 0; i < directions.length; i++ ) {
    directions[i].textContent = directions[i].textContent.split('').reverse().join('');
  }
}
```

```css
a.direction {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  max-width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="/email.php?to=rossa" class="direction">ed.dlefla-znediser-krap@assoR.S</a>
```

However, `navigator.userAgent` is not to be trusted, as malicious bots will never declare themselves as bots. So you might want to use safer methods of excluding bots, such as a link (clickable only by bots) pointing to a `php` script that would set a session variable for them. If the variable is set, just add an invisible element to your page and in the above JavaScript, instead of checking `navigator.userAgent`, check for the added element.
If you want the emails correctly indexed by certain search engines, you should exclude them from this check.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. In some points I don't follow :D – 1) I know direction:rtl is a trick here and the text shouldnt be read rtl; but why is your javascript reversing a "less trickier" solution. 2) I don't understand your suggestion for excluding bots. If you have a better trick than reversing the emails in code I'd be happy to hear it! 3) Why did you write the ellipsis dots in the html?

Comment: I guess I get what your trying to do here; but the outcome of the snippet still cuts the beginning and places the dots there; which I don't consider decent :D [Couldn't edit anymore]

Comment: I didn't add the `ellipsis` in the html. `&#x202e;` is the Unicode character for "right_to_left_override". It reverses all the remaining text until the end of the row. As for reversing the string before rendering, I don't consider it a "trick" because it gives the browser the correct string and the correct information on where it starts and where it ends. So the browser can properly cut from the actual end, not from the start. As it is now, you're giving the browser wrong information. That's the source of your problem.

Comment: Okay, but your css only approach gives me the exact same result I had; dots on the left and clipped on the left. At least this is what I see when hitting "Run code snippet" – I'm confused. :D When `&#x202e` reverses the string again; why do you still use `direction: rtl`?

Comment: If I don't, the ellipsis is placed on the right side, while the string is still cut from the left, at least in Chrome.