# CSS ellipsis on multilines does not work for RTL

Tags: css

I have this css code

```
h2 {
  display: block; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: $font-size*$line-height*$lines-to-show; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: $font-size;
  line-height: $line-height;
  -webkit-line-clamp: $lines-to-show;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[codepen snippet](https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp)

[image: without RTL]

with RTL

[image]

that work fine for multi line elpisis but when the text is RTL it does not
how can i fix this please ?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859590/text-overflow-ellipsis-fighting-with-direction-rtl

Comment: And others: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+ellipsis+RTL

Comment: these only work on single line

Comment: Isn't better using `  text-align: right;` instead of `direction:rtl;`?

Comment: I answered your question here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68997631/13658446

Answer (score 0):

Working Cross-browser Solution

This problem has been plaguing us all for years.

To help in all cases, I have laid out the CSS only approach, and a jQuery approach in case the css caveats are a problem.

Here's a CSS only solution I came up with that works in all circumstances, with a few minor caveats.

The basics are simple, it hides the overflow of the span, and sets the max height based on the line height as suggested by Eugene Xa.

Then there is a pseudo class after the containing div that places the ellipsis nicely.

Caveats

This solution will always place the ellipsis, regardless if there is need for it.

If the last line ends with an ending sentence, you will end up with four dots....

You will need to be happy with justified text alignment.

The ellipsis will be to the right of the text, which can look sloppy.

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 250px;
  float: right;
}
.text-concat {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 3.6em; /* (Number of lines you want visible) * (line-height) */
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align:justify;
  direction: rtl;
  
}
.text.ellipsis::after {
  content: "...";
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px; 
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text ellipsis">
  <span class="text-concat">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nibh eleifend cu his, porro fugit mandamus no mea. Sit tale facete voluptatum ea, ad sumo altera scripta per, eius ullum feugait id duo. At nominavi pericula persecuti ius, sea at sonet tincidunt, cu posse facilisis eos. Aliquid philosophia contentiones id eos, per cu atqui option disputationi, no vis nobis vidisse. Eu has mentitum conclusionemque, primis deterruisset est in.

Virtute feugait ei vim. Commune honestatis accommodare pri ex. Ut est civibus accusam, pro principes conceptam ei, et duo case veniam. Partiendo concludaturque at duo. Ei eirmod verear consequuntur pri. Esse malis facilisis ex vix, cu hinc suavitate scriptorem pri.
  </span>
</div>
```